# How can I use OSM in android studio to show a map

Tags: android, openstreetmap, osmdroid

I have heard about OpenStreetMap recently and I am trying to use it in android studio. I downloaded the libraries needed for OSM using 
**implementation 'org.osmdroid:osmdroid-android:6.0.2'
implementation 'org.osmdroid:osmdroid-third-party:5.6.3'**
in Gradle. The android studio automatically download the files needed.
How should my code be to be able to show a map using OSM?
I used this code but it looks as if there is something wrong with the code and so the program doesn't start.

```
private MapView         mMapView;
private MapController   mMapController;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.osm_main);
    mMapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);
    mMapView.setTileSource(TileSourceFactory.DEFAULT_TILE_SOURCE);
    mMapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    mMapController = (MapController) mMapView.getController();
    mMapController.setZoom(13);
    GeoPoint gPt = new GeoPoint(29.624471, 52.523935);
    mMapController.setCenter(gPt);
}
```

Thanks for your response in advance!

Comment: could you please add `osm_main.xml` and the relevant output of logcat?

Comment: Have you seen and followed the [instructions](https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid/wiki/How-to-use-the-osmdroid-library)?

Comment: It worked. The problem was with permissions.

Comment: Thanks Markus! I hadn't seen the instructions page before you told me

Answer (score 2):

```
package br.com.josileudorodrigues.geopoint;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.renderscript.Script;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import org.osmdroid.api.IMapController;
import org.osmdroid.config.Configuration;
import org.osmdroid.events.MapListener;
import org.osmdroid.events.ScrollEvent;
import org.osmdroid.events.ZoomEvent;
import org.osmdroid.tileprovider.tilesource.TileSourceFactory;
import org.osmdroid.util.GeoPoint;
import org.osmdroid.views.MapController;
import org.osmdroid.views.MapView;
import org.osmdroid.views.overlay.Marker;
import org.osmdroid.views.overlay.compass.CompassOverlay;
import org.osmdroid.views.overlay.compass.InternalCompassOrientationProvider;
import org.osmdroid.views.overlay.gridlines.LatLonGridlineOverlay2;
import org.osmdroid.views.overlay.mylocation.DirectedLocationOverlay;
import org.osmdroid.views.overlay.mylocation.GpsMyLocationProvider;
import org.osmdroid.views.overlay.mylocation.MyLocationNewOverlay;

import java.util.zip.Inflater;

import static android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.M;
import static java.security.AccessController.getContext;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity  implements LocationListener {

    MapView map = null;
    private MapView osm;
    private MapController mc;
    private LocationManager locationManager;
    private CompassOverlay compassOverlay;
    private DirectedLocationOverlay locationOverlay;
    private static final int PERMISSAO_REQUERIDA = 1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= M) {
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.INTERNET) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED ||
                    ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                String[] permissoes = {Manifest.permission.INTERNET, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE};
                requestPermissions(permissoes, PERMISSAO_REQUERIDA);
            }
        }
        //onde mostra a imagem do mapa
        Context ctx = getApplicationContext();
        Configuration.getInstance().load(ctx, PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(ctx));
        osm = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapaId);
        osm.setTileSource(TileSourceFactory.MAPNIK);
        osm.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        osm.setMultiTouchControls(true);

        mc = (MapController)osm.getController();
        mc.setZoom(15);

        GeoPoint center = new GeoPoint(-5.1251,-38.3640);
        mc.animateTo(center);
        addMarker(center);

        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        //locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,0,0,this);

        /* grade no mapa
        LatLonGridlineOverlay2 overlay = new LatLonGridlineOverlay2();
        osm.getOverlays().add(overlay);
        */

        osm.setMapListener(new MapListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onScroll(ScrollEvent event) {
                Log.i("Script", "onScroll()");
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onZoom(ZoomEvent event) {
                Log.i("Script", "onZoom()");
                return false;
            }
        });




    }

    public void addMarker (GeoPoint center){
        Marker marker = new Marker(osm);
        marker.setPosition(center);
        marker.setAnchor(Marker.ANCHOR_CENTER, Marker.ANCHOR_BOTTOM);
        marker.setIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icone_gps));
        osm.getOverlays().clear();
        osm.getOverlays().add(marker);
        osm.invalidate();
        marker.setTitle("Casa do Josileudo");
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        switch (requestCode) {
            case PERMISSAO_REQUERIDA: {
                // Se a solicitação de permissão foi cancelada o array vem vazio.
                if (grantResults.length > 0
                        && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    // Permissão cedida, recria a activity para carregar o mapa, só será executado uma vez
                    this.recreate();

                }

            }
        }
    }

    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

    }


    public void onPause(){
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        GeoPoint center = new GeoPoint(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());

        mc.animateTo(center);
        addMarker(center);

    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

    }
    @Override
    public void onDestroy(){
        super.onDestroy();`enter code here`
        if (locationManager != null){
            locationManager.removeUpdates(this);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Code only answers are discouraged. Please give an explanation of why your code solves the problem.